# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http,' - when Adding one project to another solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This was all working fine when I had two separate solutions - a webApi solution and a MVC solution.  I'm trying to pull the MVC solution into the WebAPI one to consolodate everything but I keep getting random reference errors.  The latest is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference.

I've searched and searched but I can't find a solution.  I've deleted my bin, rebuilt, uninstalled MVC, reinstalled it, made sure "Specific version" is set to false... I'm stuck and frustrated.  What else could be causing this?

I get the error when I try to load the MVC application.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to remove references and add them again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does one project reference the other ? Looks like framework mismatch : verify that both your projects use the same version (3.5 or 4.0) and flavor (full version, not client) of the framework